# Building Python Command Prompt Interface

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to build a simple Python Command Prompt Interface. It only needs to input text and Output something.

In the end the Interface should something look this:

[image: sample]

From Pycharm 2017 i get these error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Main/Desktop/Py Sandbox/Keylogger/test.py", line 4, in 
>       user_input = prompt('>')
>     File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\shortcuts.py", line 548, in prompt
>       eventloop=eventloop)
>     File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\shortcuts.py", line 576, in run_application
>       output=create_output(true_color=true_color))
>     File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\shortcuts.py", line 118, in create_output
>       return Win32Output(stdout)
>     File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\terminal\win32_output.py", line 80, in **init**
>       info = self.get_win32_screen_buffer_info()
>     File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\terminal\win32_output.py", line 172, in get_win32_screen_buffer_info
>       raise NoConsoleScreenBufferError
>   prompt_toolkit.terminal.win32_output.NoConsoleScreenBufferError: No Windows console found. Are you running cmd.exe?

And from the default Python IDLE i get this eroor:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Main/Desktop/adusgisdhui.py", line 4, in 
>       user_input = prompt('>')   File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\shortcuts.py",
>   line 548, in prompt
>       eventloop=eventloop)   File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\shortcuts.py",
>   line 576, in run_application
>       output=create_output(true_color=true_color))   File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\shortcuts.py",
>   line 118, in create_output
>       return Win32Output(stdout)   File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\terminal\win32_output.py",
>   line 80, in **init**
>       info = self.get_win32_screen_buffer_info()   File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\terminal\win32_output.py",
>   line 162, in get_win32_screen_buffer_info
>       self.flush()   File "C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\terminal\win32_output.py",
>   line 288, in flush
>       self.stdout.flush() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'flush'

Comment: You don't need a separate module. The `input` function is a built-in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: user input and commandline arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797/python-user-input-and-commandline-arguments)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a shell in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594560/how-to-write-a-shell-in-python)

Comment: This is not a free coding service.

Comment: Are you really wanting to build a virtual terminal with a user interface that looks rather identical to the windows/python command interface? Or just get user input from the windows command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very basic code

```
while 1:
    userinput = input(">>")

if userinput == "help":
    print("You asked for help")
elif ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great article about building command line interfaces for you python programs [CLI Python](https://opensource.com/article/17/5/4-practical-python-libraries). One of the methods is to use the `prompt_toolkit`:

```
from prompt_toolkit import prompt

while 1:
    user_input = prompt('>')
    print(user_input)
```

This will then continually ask the user for input. It also has features such as command history and auto-suggestion.

Comment: Exactly what i need but i doesn't seem to run on my PC.

Comment: My errors a mentioned above in the question because Stackoverflow doesn't allow too long comments.